# Make a S3 resource public read-only for some duration using the AWS SDK for node?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have integrated S3 to my node app and upload certain documents on to S3. Need to share these documents with a third party.
Send the URLs to the third party via an API and they will download it immediately. I want to make the S3 objects public for some duration. How do i achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 presigned URL is what you are looking for, you can use them to generate links for your third party with expiration time. I'm posting the reference links below

[Presigned url AWS official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html)

[A blog post which demonstrate presigned urls further](https://blog.fyle.in/sharing-files-using-s3-pre-signed-urls-e05d4603e067)

Answer (score 0):

With @varnit's help i was able to figure out creating a public URL for certain duration. 
I had another issue, get KEY from the resource URL.

Resolved that in Node using this:

```
AmazonS3URI(resourceUrl)
```

which returns something like this:

```
{  
   "uri":{  
      "protocol":"https:",
      "slashes":true,
      "auth":null,
      "host":"bucket.s3.region.amazonaws.com",
      "port":null,
      "hostname":"bucket.s3.region.amazonaws.com",
      "hash":null,
      "search":null,
      "query":null,
      "pathname":"/private/region%xxxxxx/file",
      "path":"/private/region%xxxxx/file",
      "href":"https://bucket.s3.region.amazonaws.com/private/region%xxxxxx/file"
   },
   "isPathStyle":false,
   "bucket":"aaaa-bbbb-ccc",
   "key":"private/xxxxx:yyyyy/file",
   "region":"region"
 }
```